# Counting rectilinear polygons

Tags: co.combinatorics

This is likely a very easy counting question inspired by some elementary geometry:

Consider a simple rectilinear polygon embedded in a plane in such a way that each of its edges is parallel to one of the coordinate axis. Two such polygons are considered *distinct* if they are not related by some composition of translation, scalar multiplication and squeeze mapping.

I would like to asses the number of such distinct simple rectilinear polygons which have $2n$ horizontal (equivalently vertical) edges for any chosen $n\in\mathbb N$.

Thank you.

Comment: squeeze mapping? 

Comment: The number of vertical edges doesn't necessarily equal the number of horizontal edges unless you make some assumption about the shape of the polygon.  (E.g.a polygon consisting of seven unit squares arranged in a C-shape.)

Comment: @Will: Horizontal or vertical scaling, e.g., $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2} x$.

Comment: @Hugh: I think you are counting edges differently?  Any C-shape
is composed of 4 horizontal and 4 vertical edges, where each edge is a segment perhaps of different length.

Comment: Counting left right turn sequences might be a good start.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.12.05

Comment: However with lrlllrll I see up to 3the possibilities, depending on how fine a distinction is made.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.12.05

Comment: What is scalar multiplication of a polygon?

Comment: Michael, scalar multiplication is just the linear transformation given by sending any point $(x,y)$ in the polygon to $(\lambda x, \lambda y).$ If the polygon is already all horizontal and vertical segments joining lattice points, and $\lambda$ is a nonzero integer, then so will the result be, except now we get more collinear edges if $\lambda \geq 2.$ Squeeze mappings would be $ 0 < \lambda < 1$ but rational. I imagine it is easy to prove that any polygon can be squeezed down to a smallest (integral) state, which I think would require only that the GCD of all segment lengths be 1.  

Comment: @Will, if "squeeze mapping" means (as Joseph writes) horizontal or vertical scaling, then it's $(x,y)\to(\lambda x,y)$, and $(x,y)\to(x,\lambda y)$. Under that interpretation we find, for example, that all rectangles are equivalent. But only OP knows if that's the intended meaning. 

Comment: Joseph O'Rourke and Gerry Myerson correctly realized the intended meaning of the perhaps too ambiguous term "squeeze mapping". As Gerry noted, it is true that under the defined identification all rectangles (that is $n=1$ simple rectilear polygons) are equivalent. I hope this clears up some interpretational issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of right turns must always be 4 more than the number of left turns. This is the only constraint on turn sequences. Proof: Take the minimal impossible sequence satisfying this property. It must contain RR, so it is either RRRR or contains RRL. Delete the RL, find an example, and then add a small "tab" off the corner. If it's RRRR, draw a rectangle.

The number of words like that should be a fairly standard combinatorics problem. I don't know the exact formula.

Already with 6 turns, though, the number of distinct polygons is infinite. In assembling an L-shape, I have 6 degrees of freedom counting translation, and you only have a 4-dimensional space of symmetries.

Comment: Or to be more explicit, if we are interpreting the problem correctly, then the L-shapes consisting of an $n\times1$ rectangle upright with a $2\times1$ base all have 6 sides and are inequivalent for distinct $n$. 

Comment: If I'm reading the OP correctly, the condition was that there are $2n$ horizontal and $2n$ vertical segments, so the L-shapes are not valid examples. Fortunately, this isn't really an issue, as we can just use a larger staircase polygon.

Comment: In my innitial question I indeed only considered boundaries composed of 2n vertical and 2n horizontal line segments. But that restriction steams only from the geometric background in which the question originaly arised and there is no particular reason why L-shapes and simmilar objects couldn't be considered as well. Anyway thank you for the answer!

Comment: Erm, I thought we did not allow self-crossings...

Comment: Neither my example nor my combinatoric proof nor Gerry's example includes any self-crossings.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question entirely thinking it asked about polygons built of 4n segments of equal length parallel to the axis. :)